# Properties null at component drawing time?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

I have got problem accessing a property of a component. I want to use this property to decide whether to include a particular child component.

For example:
***MyMainView.mxml*** lists this component

```
<view:AnotherView id="anotherView" aPresenter="{thePresenter}"/>
```

Now ***AnotherView.mxml*** has a property

```
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    [Bindable]
    public var aPresenter:APresenter;
]]></fx:Script>
```

and then in this ***AnotherView.mxml*** when I am adding something e.g.

```
<s:Spacer height="10" includeInLayout="{aPresenter.id != -1}"/>
```

*aPresenter* is still null hence the spacer get drawn no matter what. On the other hand if I use *aPresenter* for a dataProvider it works

```
<mx:Repeater id="addressDetailsRepeaterView" dataProvider="{presenter.arrayOfFields}">
</mx:Repeater>
```

Can somebody please help me understand the flow of events on creation of a flex component and how I can use the *aPresenter* property in .

Thanks

Comment: Where do you put `<mx:Repeater>...</mx:Repeater>` in `MyMainView.mxml` or `AnotherView.mxml`? Also how is `thePresenter` declared in `MyMainView.mxml` and how do you change its value?

Comment: Have you read the Lifecycle docs? Read this http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html and this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html

Comment: mx:Repeater is not in MyMainView.mxml, its in AnotherView.mxml... and thePresenter in MyMainView.mxml is indeed bindable hence usable in the AnotherView.mxml... Only that its null upto a certain point i.e. drawing of things within AnotherView.mxml

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here...

Answer (score 0):

Try includeInLayout="{aPresenter != null}"